# Синий экран. Какое оборудование может его вызывать?

Tags: windows

В общем у меня такая проблема. Купил ноутбук и ровно после гарантийного срока(через год), стабильно начал вылетать синий экран. Причины синего экрана были всякие разные(коды ошибок, если точнее). Я решил переустановить винду. На первое время это помогло и потом опять начались вылеты. Причем вылеты очень странные, они могут долго не появляться, но потом за день раз 20 появиться. Потом я еще раз снес винду и это помогло на некоторое время. Тогда, очевидно что проблема в оборудовании, ведь не может же такого быть при полной переустановки windows. Затем я решил протестировать оборудование(ОЗУ, HDD). С хдд было все в порядке, а вот озу выдавал какие то ошибки. В связи с этим я заменил плашку озу и опять же мне помогло это где-то на месяц. Сейчас по прежнему неожиданные, непредсказуемые вылеты, причину вызова которых я абсолютно понять не могу. Я уже все перегуглил, но полезного ничего не нашел. Вот думаю hdd заменить, но наврятли это что-то даст. Может кто встречался с подобной ситуацией, подскажите что может быть не так.

Comment: Вы бы хоть коды ошибок последних приложили)

Comment: Да я их уже не смотрю, они каждый раз разные и гуглить причину их появления как то бессмысленно. Гуглишь мол код ошибки (число), выдает что-то вроде - данная ошибка может быть вызвана многими причинами(и огромный их перечень). И так на каждую ошибку, а если учесть , что они каждый раз разные, то отыскать решение анриал.

Comment: Так вы сейчас нас просите гадать на кофейной гуще. Более того - без самой этой гущи даже

Comment: Хорошо, приведу коды останова которые недавно встречал: PAGE FAULT IN NONPAGED AREA, driver irql less or equal,  System Thread Exception Not Handled. Вот эти три были на этой неделе, какие то чаще, какие то реже.

Comment: Если материнка сбоит, то замена ОЗУ не поможет. Еще может быть, что источник питания глючит, тогда вся система работает криво.

Comment: А если поставить linux, то это поможет? Там же нет синих экранов) Либо там есть что-то аналогичное?

Comment: Вариантов много. 1. Кривой драйвер. 2. Память сбоит. 3. Сбоит одно из устройств на шине. Мне синий экран давал Outpost Firewall. Если при замене памяти ошибка стала появляться реже - попробуйте снизить частоту работы памяти в биосе (поменять тайминги на более щадящие).

Comment: Чем тестировал винт? Чем тестировал оперативу? Откуда качал винду? Какую оперативу купил на замену? Чё там по температурам во время работы?

Answer (score 1):

Скачиваете программу BlueScreenView(http://bluescreenview.ru/ ). Открываете её после очередного BSOD'а. И смотрете какой файл вызвал ошибку в работе системы. Записываете. Ждете второй BSOD. Проделываете те же действия. Если файлы/устроство с которым эти файлы связаны совпадают, то вы нашли проблемное железо. Так же для полной уверенности можете проделать все это 3-й раз

Comment: Как правило синий экран вызывает ntoskrnl.exe. Причин как обычно море.

Comment: @james, тогда надо проверять каждое устройство отдельно. У меня была проблемы с оперативкой(битую продали) и с помощью встроенных функций windows(панель управления - администрирование - средство проверки памяти windows) выяснил что именно проблема с ней была. Думаю есть такие же утилиты для проверки других компонентов

Answer (score 1):

> А если поставить linux, то это поможет?

Если железо сбоит, то никакой Линукс не поможет. Теоретически, другая ОС может как-то по-другому нагружать железо и на некоторое время сбой может пропасть. Но как Вы описываете проблему, у вас наблюдается деградация железа. Сначала все работало, а потом стало сбоить все чаще и чаще. Попробуйте временно поставить другой источник питания, хотя для ноутов обычно трудно достать другой источник питания. Замена материнки тоже вариант, но тоже доступный лишь для специализированных мастерских и к тому же материнка стоит ДЕНЕГ. Так что либо дожидаться, когда ноут откажет совсем и нести его в ремонт. Либо сразу покупать новый. Советую брать проверенные марки из первой тройки производителей. Иначе всегда будет такая катавасия.

И да, тут советовали понизить частоту ОЗУ. Это может помочь. Если у Вас есть такие настройки в БИОС, то попробуйте понизить частоту ОЗУ.

И еще один вариант - Вы пользуетесь какой-то левой программой, которая криво написана, потом деградирует и начинает Вам гадить. Попробуйте переставить винду и хотя бы какое-то время не ставить ничего, кроме офиса, браузера и прочего проверенного софта. Никаких игрушек, никаких танков и прочего. И поглядите, не исчезнут ли сбои. У меня был случай, когда после ХХ лет после установки давно неиспользуемая программа оживилась и запустила демона, который работал на повышенном приоритете давил вообще ВСЕ. Пока не снесли в защищенном режиме, ничего не помогало.